# Javascript Prevent One Part of a Function From Running Until Other is Completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I use to reload an Iframe, and I want it to do more things after the Iframe is reloaded rather than at the same time.

```
var heightArray = [];

function changeScroll() {
    console.log(Number(heightArray[0]));
    $('#vidList').contents().scrollTop(Number(heightArray[0]));
}

function changeVideo(source, title, desc) {
    heightArray = [];
    $("#current-video_html5_api").attr('src', source);
    $(".vidTitle").html(title);
    $(".vidDesc").html(desc);
    document.getElementById('vidList').contentWindow.location.reload();
        //Stuff I want to happen after ^ this happens
    var vidListHeight = $('#vidList').contents().scrollTop();
    heightArray.push(vidListHeight);
    console.log(heightArray);
    changeScroll();
}
```

How would I go about making it so all the things within `changeVideo()` that appear after `document.getElementById('vidList').contentWindow.location.reload();` actually **happen** after it. In other words, how do I make the function finish running each thing individually before running the next (i.e First, heightArray is cleared, then the source of `curreent-video_html5_api` changes, etc.)

Comment: In the iframe when it loads, you could call a function to the iframe's parent that does the stuff. Or you could listen to the iframe's `load` event but I don't think that'd be allowed. In any case you will probably stumble into security issues.

Comment: @Jan I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner >.< I got it working now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All your code runs synchronously instead of reloading a frame.

So, you need to call you code that you need run after you need call asynchronously after reloading that frame.

Frame has `onload` event that you could subscribe for:

```
document.getElementById('vidList').load = function() {
var vidListHeight = $('#vidList').contents().scrollTop();
    heightArray.push(vidListHeight);
    console.log(heightArray);
    changeScroll();
};
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work, I tried Jan's solution and it did work, and I don't see how I didn't think of it sooner >.< either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Are there any errors in console? Does it printing a result of `console.log(heightArray);` to console?

Comment: There were no errors, it just still loaded all at the same time.

Comment: @Calebbait If you update your code, we could deal with it.